# Problem of trigonometry

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I have a big problem of trigonometry, I want to convert the yaw of my robot from quaternion to radians using GetYaw() function, it's working pretty well, but I still have a problem.

I am using cos and sin functions but
the robot orientation is now in radians but it's going from -pi to +pi, why wont it be like any normal trigonometric circle, from 0 to 2pi ?

Here there a way to change that ? Im pretty stuck at the moment and my brain is smelting, thank you in advance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15924/problem-of-trigonometry/) by [shenki](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3179/shenki/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 39 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo uses a right-handed coordinate system. Most models are created with the x axis pointing out the front, and +z pointing up. Yaw behaves as one would expect from trigonometry. Looking from above the yaw angle increase when the model rotates counter-clockwise, and decreases when the model rotates clockwise.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shenki](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3179/shenki/) on 2017-04-20**:
hello, I Am retarded, thank you for your answer